# Is it possible to supress reminders on the phone?

Tags: reminders, calendars

I synchronise with a corporate Exchange account and am in the situation that I get meeting reminders pop up on both my phone, as well as in Outlook on the PC.

Is it possible to keep the reminder in Outlook, but not have them pop up on the phone? It can be annoying to have to dismiss them on both devices.

Comment: What version of WP are you using? With WP8.1 you can go to settings/notifications+ actions and disable it.

Answer (score -1):

Haven't tried it but you can have a go with it:

```
- go to http://account.live.com/
- Click Notifications on the right side 
- Manage email preferences 
- Under your preffered email click "Change"
- Choose Calender options page near the bottom
- ???
- Profit :)
```

Comment: This only manages the reminders for Hotmail/Outlook.com, and not for Exchange accounts; it also seems to apply across all devices, and would also affect Outlook, as well as my phone.